# OpenGL ES 2.0 Camera Issues

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working with Android and OpenGL ES 2.0 and I am having an issue that I can't really formulate into a solid question.  In the image, https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUXLt.png, I basically have a shape to represent a ship in the middle and when it's moved to the side it gets stretched toward the vanishing point.  What I am wanting to accomplish is to have the ship maintain most of its shape when it is moved.  I believe it may be due to my matrices but every resource I've looked seems to use the same method.

```
//Setting up the projection matrix
final float ratio = (float) width / height;
final float left = -ratio;
final float right = ratio;
final float bottom = -1.0f;
final float top = 1.0f;
final float near = 1.0f;
final float far = 1000.0f;
Matrix.frustumM(projection_matrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);

//Setting the view matrix
Matrix.setLookAtM(view_matrix, 0, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

//Setting the model matrix
Matrix.setIdentityM(model_matrix, 0);
Matrix.translateM(model_matrix, 0, 2f, 0f, 0f);

//Setting the model-view-projection matrix
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvp_matrix, 0, view_matrix, 0, model_matrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvp_matrix, 0, GL.projection_matrix, 0, mvp_matrix, 0);
GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvp_matrix_location, 1, false, mvp_matrix, 0);
```

The shaders are very basic as well:

```
private final static String vertex_shader = 
      "uniform mat4 u_mvp_matrix;"
    + "attribute vec4 a_position;"
    + "void main()"
    + "{"
    + "  gl_Position = u_mvp_matrix * a_position;"
    + "}";

private final static String fragment_shader = 
       "precision mediump float;"
     + "void main()"
     + "{"
     + "  gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);"
     + "}";
```

Any thoughts/insight is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is normal - that is how perspective projection should look like. Although in your case it looks really stretched one - with wide field of view.

Try using instead of `frustumM` method `perspectiveM`(projection_matrix, 0, 45.0f, ratio, near, far).
Or if you must use `frustumM`, calculate left/right/bottom/top like this:

```
float fov = 60; // degrees, try also 45, or different number if you like
top = tan(fov * PI / 360.0f) * near;
bottom = -top;
left = ratio * bottom;
right = ratio * top;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been banging my head trying to figure out how to change the perspective in a meaningful way, until I met this answer. I was missing the field of view logic. Had a Eureka moment when I saw your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any perspective effect at all, then use [Matrix.orthoM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html#orthoM%28float%5b%5d,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) instead of Matrix.frustumM.

To just make the perspective effect less extreme, you need to reduce the field of view -- That is, increase `near` or bring `top` and `bottom` closer to zero. (You probably want `right = top * ratio`, and similarly with `left` if you're going to fiddle with `top` and `bottom` values.)