# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Mesh is getting distorted by Y and Z axes

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm trying to display simple mesh, but I've got the following problem: 
when I'm trying to translate mesh, or specifying most of perspective matrix parameters (using the Matrix.frustumM method), my mesh is getting distorted. It shrinks by the Z axis, and stretches by the Y axis.

My camera matrix code:

```
Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0,-3, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

My projection matrix code (copy-pasted from here: [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891289/opengl-es-2-0-camera-issues/8891510#8891510/) )

```
float near = 1.0f;
float far = 10.0f;
float ratio = (float) width/height;
float fov = 60;
float top = (float)Math.tan(fov * Math.PI / 360.0f) * near;
float bottom = -top;
float left = ratio * bottom;
float right = ratio * top;

Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
```

My vertex shader code:

```
private static String vertexShaderCode =            
"uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +

"attribute vec4 aPosition;" +
"attribute vec2 aTextureCoordIn;"+

"varying vec2 vTextureCoordOut;"+

"void main() {"+
"   vTextureCoordOut = aTextureCoordIn;"+
"   gl_Position = aPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +            
"}";
```

Mesh is scaled using the 0.2 multiplier, using the following code:

```
mModelMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, rotateX, 1, 0, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, rotateY, 0, 1, 0);
Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, rotateZ, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.scaleM(mModelMatrix, 0,  scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ);
Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0,  translateX, translateY, translateZ);
```

And mvp matrix multiplied using this:

```
float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];

Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
```

I have tried solutions from the following topics:[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891289/opengl-es-2-0-camera-issues/8891510#8891510/),[second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200245/android-opengl-es-2-0-scene-scrolling/13270443#13270443), but without success.

Screenshots:

[image: first]
[image: second]

I have also found that when I'm using the following projection matrix, and dont translate mesh, it looks correct:
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 6);
Screen:

[image: correct]

I've tried to find solution for several hours, but without any effect. I'm sure that the problem with my matrices, but I dont know how to resolve it.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a huge confusion with android tutorials.. The way you multiply your matrices dictates to multiply the position in the vertex shader main function the same way, thus:

instead of:

```
"gl_Position = aPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
```

do:

```
"gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;" +
```