# Sphere changes its shape when it moves to corner in webgl(three.js)

Tags: three.js, geometry

Sphere is changing its shape to egg when it is moved corners of browser. Is there any possible solution so that its shape is not distorted. It is live example of three.js.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(OpenGL ES) Objects away from view centre are stretched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457210/opengl-es-objects-away-from-view-centre-are-stretched)

Answer (score 1):

This is how perspective distortions work with too wide angle. You might heard of it from the photography - called "Fish-Eye" effect.

To fix that you need a narrower field-of-view setting (usually supplied to camera on initialization). Or switch to Orthographic camera altogether.

Similar answered questions:

[(OpenGL ES) Objects away from view centre are stretched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457210/opengl-es-objects-away-from-view-centre-are-stretched)

[OpenGL ES 2.0 Camera Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891289/opengl-es-2-0-camera-issues)

[Android openGL ES 2.0 scene scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13200245/android-opengl-es-2-0-scene-scrolling)

Comment: Here is my other question related to it...                                                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091248/orthographic-and-perspective-camera-issue?noredirect=1#comment33508344_22091248