# Orthographic and Perspective Camera issue

Tags: three.js, projection

This image is using perspective camera but sphere shape is distorted when it is moving away from the center.

[image]

this image is using Orthographic camera but spheres and cuboid are not in 3D...

[image]

can any one suggest possible solution for this to get 3D effect without sphere distorting its shape...

Comment: Use a smaller field of view. The higher your field of view the more things distort at the edges. [Go here](https://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/aquarium.html), click the tiny asterisk next to *change view*, drag the `fieldOfView` slider, notice how distorted things become the wider the field of view.

Comment: You can prevent the distorted spheres by using a `THREE.Sprite` instead: http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_sprites.html. If for some reason that is not acceptable, then you need to dynamically scale/rotate each sphere so it is a properly-oriented ellipsoid; the proper ellipsoid will project to a circle. That is a doable math problem.

Comment: Thank you for your comments but can you please tell me how to scale sphere depends on position so that distortion does not happen using perspective camera... And I don't want to make scaling(Z) to 0 as I need to rotate the sphere.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly correct. Spheres distortion and cuboid perspective effect are both caused by the same perspective projection properties.

One possible solution would be to split your scene in two parts:

- render background (cuboid) with perspective projection
- render spheres using orthographic projection

Another solution would be to draw everything with orthographic and modify your cuboid to be a trapezoid, so that it only *looks* like to be in perspective.

Having perspective and no distortions sounds mutually exclusive if you think about it. Imagine a sphere consists of 2 parts - front and rear. Now you say you need objects farther from camera to be smaller, but at the same time you say you want front and rear of sphere to be the same size - not possible. You can achieve desired effect with orthographic projection if you manually specify spheres size to be smaller when they are farther. Or alternatively you can use perspective projection and scale your spheres to be flat by depth axis (but keep the normals to preserve proper lighting)

Comment: I want Everything in perspective projection because spheres need to move like in 3D i.e., its size should be big when it come front and small when it go back which is not possible using Orthogonal... its perfect in perspective but shape is distorted...  1. first sol is not possible because second scene over rides first scene... and second doesnt meet my requirement

Comment: This is mutually exclusive if you think about it. Imagine a sphere consists of 2 parts - front and rear. Now you say you need objects farther from camera to be smaller, but at the same time you say you want front and rear of sphere to be the same size - not possible. You can achieve desired effect with orthographic projection if you manually specify spheres size to be smaller when they are farther. Or alternatively you can use perspective projection and scale your spheres to be flat by depth axis (but keep the normals to preserve proper lighting)

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of second sol before posting... I will make a try as drawing cuboid manually in orthographic makes difficult for me...

Comment: Maybe if you post your desired result image we will be able to achieve desired effect better.

Comment: Try making spheres flat (scale by depth axis to 0.01%)

Comment: Thank you for your comments but can you please tell me how to scale sphere depends on position so that distortion does not happen using perspective camera... And I don't want to make scaling(Z) to 0 as I need to rotate the sphere.

Comment: Do the scaling AFTER rotation and it will be fine.

Comment: Can you please explain it, I mean i rotated x,y, and z axis to (+1) and scaled all three axis to (1) and result is the same(it is still distorted).

Comment: I think you have to ask a separate question, because I'm not familiar with how exactly `Three.js` handles objects transformations. Generally you need to scale rotated object vertices (rotate first, scale second, move to place - last) but keep the normals as they were.